# Fetch -> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in chrome console

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to make a fetch request that takes a long time (2-5m), but I'm getting this error message in the Chrome console after around 1m30:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

So, I tried to wrap my fetch request in a timer, like that:

```
   function timeout(ms, promise) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          reject(new Error("timeout"))
        }, ms)
        promise.then(resolve, reject)
      })
    }

    timeout(600000, fetch('/refresh')).then(function(response) {
        response.json().then((data) => {
            window.location.reload()
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("TIMEOUT")
    });
```

**But I'm still getting the same error after around 1m30, and also the console log 'TIMEOUT'.. Why?**

Thanks

Comment: perhaps because the server is not sending anything - hence "empty response" - oh, wait ... you get a timeout ... so, after a timeout, the response will be empty of course - the timeout is in the request ... so, waiting 60 seconds in a setTimeout isn't going to change the slow response from the server

Comment: but the server is sending a response, only after what needs to be done is completed, which takes around 2 to 5 minutes

Comment: The issue is, `fetch` timeout is probably (by the look of it) 90 seconds ... the code you found and used only allows you to "set" a SHORTER timeout. It doesn't allow a longer timeout, because the internals of fetch seems to "hardcode" 90 seconds - use XMLHttpRequest instead, which does have a settable timeout

Comment: I tried with this:    `xhr.open('GET', '/refresh', true);
 xhr.timeout = 600000; 
 xhr.onload = function () {
     this.setState({loading: false});
     window.location.reload();
 };
 xhr.send(null);` and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: you're still getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` ??? - note `this.setState` in that `onload` will fail - wrong `this` in there

Comment: Yes I do.. :( removing `this.setState` didn't change anything :(

Comment: can you tell me a bit about the server side? It could be that the server side has a 90 second timeout

Comment: here's the server-side route:

Comment: `app.get("/refresh", (req, res) => {
    var process = spawn('python3', ["scrape.py"]);
    process.stdout.on('data', function (data){
        if ((data.toString().indexOf("***scraping*finished***") > -1)) {
            res.json({done: "done"});
        }
    });
});`

Comment: basically it's running a python script to get some data and do some other stuff Python's very good for, and then it's sending back a response once I flush it in Python.

Comment: So, it's actually `nodejs` + `express` that runs the python?

Comment: exactly. It works if the python script takes 10 seconds, I get a response on my front-end. But Not when it takes a long time (like usual, I'd say 4 minutes)

Comment: so, you're using JSON simply to notify `done` - one workaround is to send a `.` for example for each `on('data'` ... then simply `res.end()` when done ... and don't expect json in the client, just wait for the response to complete

Comment: But when I do `res.json({nothing: "nothing"});` I get `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: well ... why do that?

Comment: But, how do I a send back a `.` or whatever then?

Comment: `res.send('.')`

Comment: it gives the same error

Comment: after 90 seconds?

Comment: yes!! obiviously

Comment: well, it's not obvious to me!! Oh, just realised that the python process probably isn't outputting during the processing, only once it is complete, therefore there is no `data` events until completed?

Comment: just realised you can't do multiple res.send anyway ... however, take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppfk0rm7/) - not sure it'll help, but it seems it should

Comment: Hey, first thanks a lot for writing this fiddle. Sadly I just tried with this piece of code, and when I do /refresh my local server returns only "0" after a few seconds (in the html page, not the chrome console). Nothing in the Node console & in the React dev environment.

Comment: 0 means the process finished without error (after a few seconds!) 0 is the "exit code" of the spawned process

Comment: not sure why you'd get 0 in the HTML page, **your** code does nothing with the requests response, so neither does my example - also, what do you expect in the node console? your node code didn't output anything to the console either, at least, not the code you posted.

Comment: actually it works, thanks so much!!